# Cannot read from 20 metres away - even with glasses

Tags: glasses, myopia-nearsightedness, contact-lenses, blurry-vision

I have had bad eyesight from birth, and i mean bad. My lenses on my glasses are as thick as anything, without them everything is blurry unless it is a couple of inches away from my face.

Anyway, upon till now this hasn't been a major problem for me as bad eyesight is quite common, I sat at or near the front in class and just got on with my life with my glasses on permanently. Now I've decided to try to learn to drive (In the UK) and before applying for my provisional, i saw a eyesight requirement page so i proceeded to it only to see that i should be able to read a cars registration from about 20m away, so i went ahead and tested it on a few cars on a bright sunny day but i CAN NOT.

No matter how hard i squint, or how close i bring my glasses to my eyes, the text on the plate is just to blurry for me to interpret. i think i can read it from about 15 metres but rules are rules right?

I was hoping for some suggestions as to what to go about doing to resolve this? I mean i need to drive its not an option and i cant get lasik until im 21 (im currently 17).

i was thinking about trying contact lenses but how much difference will they make compared to glasses?

Comment: What did your (or high street) optician say?

Comment: i didnt speak to them yet to be honest. but i did ask a few years ago if my vision was okay to drive (this was a hospital optician, not a high street one) and he said "yeah should be".

Comment: The only real way of finding out your options is to see an optician.  They will be able to test your prescription to see if an adjustment is needed.  They will also be able to advise on contact lenses.

Comment: In high myopia (extreme near sightedness) the best possible vision correction can be received with a hard contact, after that, a soft contact.  Hard Rigid Gas Permeable lens (RGP) that take a month to get fully adjusted to.  They aren't painful during the adjustment period, just a bit annoying at first, and then as your eyes adapt to them, you gradually forget about them completely.   How many diopters of correction do you require?  Do you have astigmatism?  Is your eye and retina otherwise healthy?  Discuss all of these things with an Optometrist or Ophthalmologist.